# "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" warning avoidance

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I try to run this code in a Jupyter environment and I get "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" in spite of the the fact that I am using  df.loc .

How do I avoid this error message for the following code? All I am trying to do is round the values in the 'Score' column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['Orange',11.111],['Orange',12.1111111],['Orange',13.111111],
        ['Orange',14.11111],['Orange',15.111111],['Orange',16.111111],
        ['Orange',17.11111],['Orange',18.11111], 
        ['StrawBerry',22.11111],['StrawBerry',23.11111],
        ['StrawBerry',24.11111], 
        ['StrawBerry',25.11111],['StrawBerry',26.11111], 
        ['StrawBerry',27.111111]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Fruit', 'Score'])
df

df['Score'] = df.loc[:,'Score'].apply(lambda x: np.round(x,decimals=4))

print (df['Score'])
print (df)
```

Comment: I upvote this just because this question includes a fully working minimal example with pandas without having to ask for it. :) To your question: I can't reproduce your error. It works for me in Jupyter as well as in IPython console without displaying an error.

Comment: Well I tried it twice today. Initially it did give me this error and the second time I ran it , therror disappeared but I couldn't understand why the error message appeared even in the first instance. In another instance (other similar code), I have had the code running smoothly without the warning message on the first run and then coming up when I ran the code the second time around.

Comment: Hmm...  Do you have any globals or other variables with the same name? Do you use slicing to create views on which you do calculations?

Comment: Please add your Pandas version, i.e. `pd.__version__`.

Comment: 0.23.4 is the one I have .

Comment: No other global variables

Comment: I managed to recreate the error message with Pandas 0.19.0 . So it is the version of pandas which creates the error message. Thanks @jpp

Comment: Also thanks @Scotty1 for confirming that you don't get the same error message.